# PowerShell compare an .EXE version to an .MSI version

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, exe, comparison-operators

Good Morning, I'm working on a script that will compare the version of an installed .exe to an .msi in another location. If the versions don't match it'll install the newer .msi. I have to code to get the version numbers but it keeps saying they don't match; and they do, but also don't.

```
.EXE Version is 9.1.3.3108
.MSI Version is 9.1.3
```

Below is my code

```
Function Get-MsiDBVersion {
    param (
        [string] $fn
    )

    try {
        $FullPath = (Resolve-Path $fn).Path
        $windowsInstaller = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer

        $database = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $Null, 
                $windowsInstaller, @($FullPath, 0)
            )

        $q = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'"
        $View = $database.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $database, ($q)
            )

        $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)

        $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null
            )

        $productVersion = $record.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "StringData", "GetProperty", $Null, $record, 1
            )

        $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)

        return $productVersion

    } catch {
        throw "Failed to get MSI file version the error was: {0}." -f $_
    }
}

$RACToolsVersion = Get-MsiDBVersion "C:\Source\BuildSource\Laptop\02-AdminCenter\RACTools\RACTools_x64.msi"

if((get-item "C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\rac5\racadm.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion -match $RACToolsVersion){
>>     write-host "yes match"
>> }else{
>>     write-host "no match"}
```

When I run this, I always get the result of `no match`

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before - see here: https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/2016/12/13/query-windows-installer-msi-using-powershell/

and specifically the note at the bottom!

"When writing Powershell functions to return single values (a string, for example) please ensure you pipe any calls to ‘Execute’ or ‘Close’ to ‘Out-Null’ (please see above).  This will stop the function from returning a System.Object[] (since Powershell functions return the whole output from the function, and not just the value after the ‘return’ statement)!"

So in your case, your function was returning leading spaces, which can be fixed like so (notice the out-null's):

```
Function Get-MsiDBVersion {
    param (
        [string]$fn
    )

    try {
        $FullPath = (Resolve-Path $fn).Path
        $windowsInstaller = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer

        $database = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $Null, 
                $windowsInstaller, @($FullPath, 0)
            )

        $q = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion'"
        $View = $database.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $database, ($q)
            )

        $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null) | Out-Null

        $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null
            )

        $productVersion = $record.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "StringData", "GetProperty", $Null, $record, 1
            )

        $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null) | Out-Null


        return $productVersion

    } catch {
        throw "Failed to get MSI file version the error was: {0}." -f $_
    }
}
```